# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger

Tags: android, flutter, compiler-errors

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
E/flutter (10075): If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.
E/flutter (10075): If you're running a test, you can call the `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` as the first line in your test's `main()` method to initialize the binding.
E/flutter (10075): #0      defaultBinaryMessenger.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:76:7)
E/flutter (10075): #1      defaultBinaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:89:4)
E/flutter (10075): #2      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:140:62)
E/flutter (10075): #3      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314:35)
E/flutter (10075): #4      OptionalMethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:429:36)
E/flutter (10075): #5      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations (package:flutter/src/services/system_chrome.dart:236:35)
E/flutter (10075): #6      main (package:entremuros/main.dart:8:16)
E/flutter (10075): #7      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:239:25)
E/flutter (10075): #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
E/flutter (10075): #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (10075): #10     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
E/flutter (10075): #11     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1502:12)
E/flutter (10075): #12     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:231:5)
E/flutter (10075): #13     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:307:19)
E/flutter (10075): #14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
E/flutter (10075):
```

```
void main(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Recently I updated my versions, I had problems even with AndroidX, I managed to get out of that chaos, but now I have this one, in some other threads they solve by adding the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized ()` line; but in my case no, it may be that in my main view is absent from some method?

Step to leave also a code snippet from the other view is a StatefulWidget

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    validarUsrPrimeraVez();

    super.initState();

  }

  Future<List<Producto>> getPipeteodeCesar() async {
    return await ClientDatabaseProvider.db.getAllProductos();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return
      Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Producto>>(
            initialData: nombre,
            future: ClientDatabaseProvider.db.getAllProductos(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<List<Producto>> snapshot) {
              if(bandera) { // 00
                return SafeArea(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _containerBackground(context,screenWidth,screenHeight),
                      _containerLogo(screenWidth,screenHeight),
                      _OneButton(context),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }else{
                return SafeArea(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _containerBackground(context,screenWidth,screenHeight),
                      _containerLogo(screenWidth,screenHeight),
                      _botones(context),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
        ),
      );
  }
```